# How do I prevent STRUTS from persisting selections?

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts1

I am using JAVA STRUTS.  I have an html form with an ActionForm class associated with it and the controls are created using  tags.  As I understand it, STRUTS will persist selections on an html form even if the form is refreshed.  I need to prevent this behavior and force it to rebind the values from the ActionForm object.

Basically, I have a form with a radio button group that allows the user to select A, B, or C.  I have an ActionForm that has the property "selection = A" set when the form is loaded.  If the user selects B and submits it, the form is correctly set to "selection = B" and all is good.  However, when I refresh the page, the ActionForm gets reset to "selection = A" (confirmed through debugging), but the radio buttons have B selected!

Does anyone know why this is or how I can prevent it from happening?

Comment: Are you using sturts or struts 2?

Comment: `ActionForm`s are Struts related. I retag from Struts2 to Struts so that you'll obtain a better help here, but I strongly suggest you to migrate to Struts2 ASAP...

Comment: Thanks Andrea!  I'm just a contractor hired to look at a specific part of the site, so I can't upgrade them myself.  I know they recently upgraded the struts version, but I guess they didn't make it as far as v2.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your post i thought it was belongs to `struts2` so,

`According to struts2 it is not possible means, you have to give the static value or you have to make in programmatic manner  through JPA (or)your java code`.

For JPA you refer this link it is helpful [JPA way](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/33168.html)

```
This explanation is refer to static way
```

First in jsp page you have to `import struts2 tags` through `taglib uri` then it shows the available struts2 tags in those tags you have to select `<s:radio></s:radio> tag`

```
eg:
<s:radio label="Selections" name="your name" list="#{'A':'A','B':'B'}" value="2" />
```

in this code i typed the value as 2 so, it select B as a default if you remove the value it won't select any default values.

```
Basically what i am trying to say here is without value it won't select any radio buttons 

you have to give value through static way or dynamic way.
```

For dynamic way you can refer this link [dynamic radio button](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sradio-radio-button-example/)